# Postgres no results from linked tables where linked values are null

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I have this query:

```
update CA_San_Francisco as p 
set geo = u.geo 
from parcels_union u 
where u.street_number = p.street_number 
    and u.street_name = p.street_name 
    and u.street_type = p.street_type 
    and u.street_direction = p.street_direction 
    and u.street_unit = p.street_unit
```

However it does not update any rows where both fields are null. In other words, if there is no value in street_direction for both tables, I get no result even though they are both the same - both null values.

I get that something can't be = Null. So how do I get all of the results?

Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the field is `NULL` and if it is then change it to something you can check for.

For instance, you can change your `Where` clause to the following

```
where coalesce(u.street_number,'') = coalesce(p.street_number,'')
    and coalesce(u.street_name,'') = coalesce(p.street_name,'') 
    and coalesce(u.street_type,'') = coalesce(p.street_type,'') 
    and coalesce(u.street_direction,'') = coalesce(p.street_direction,'') 
    and coalesce(u.street_unit,'') = coalesce(p.street_unit,'')
```

But if there are multiple rows that have `NULL` in these columns then you will get unexpected assignments in your update...

Comment: Less elegant than I was hoping for, but not too weighty and does seem to work. Thanks!